# Unable to set NULL value in a column with type uuid which is nullable in Postgresql using Node JS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-pg-pool

I am using node pg client, and I have a table

```
create table test(
   id uuid not null constraint transactions_pkey primary key,
   name varchar(255),
   test_id uuid
);
```

I am trying to update test_id to NULL but I am unable to do so programmatically.

Here is my update query

```
dbo.query('UPDATE test SET test_id = $1 WHERE id = $2',['null','f2aasced-5633-419c-95d3-3868dd3c9c53'])
```

It gives me an error

`error: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "NULL"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just try to insert string 'null' into uuid column. Try

```
dbo.query('UPDATE test SET test_id = $1 WHERE id = $2',[null,'f2aasced-5633-419c-95d3-3868dd3c9c53'])
```